# Is there a simple equation allowing a calculation of the probability that a standard normal variable is greater than a given value?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a standard normal variable, $$\epsilon\sim\phi(1, 0).$$

I have learned that, for some constant $A$, it is true that $$P(\epsilon<A)=N(A),$$

which is easy enough to find out. But what if I want to find $P(\epsilon>A)$? Is there a similarly simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(\epsilon > A) = 1- P(\epsilon < A)=1-N(A)$$

Comment: I'm quite embarrassed that I didn't think about that.

Comment: no worries. it happens  to me too. Note that $P(\epsilon < A) = P(\epsilon \leq A)$